# Macbook Pro 13 2017 suddenly shutdown then stuck at apple logo

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mojave

I have a Macbook Pro 13-inch, 2017 model, and an original OS. I'm currently using Mojave. I updated two weeks ago and everything seems running smoothly. But last night, my Macbook just suddenly shuts down and it was stuck on apple logo with no loading or progress bar. First, I waited for 10 minutes when I rebooted. Then I noticed that my Macbook is hot. So I turned it off. Then I tried the following methods when rebooting:

- Used CMD + R, but it doesn't go to recovery mode.
- Used CMD + Option + R, nothing happens after recovery using internet.
- Used Shift to enter safe mode, it doesn't go to safe mode.
- Used CMD + Option + P + R, it doesn't fix anything. Still stuck at apple logo.
- Used CMD + S, I just showed a verbose mode and the line said "End RandomSeed"
- Used CMD + V, the last line prompted "End RandomSeed" and then freezes.
- Pressed D, but nothing was seen defective in hardware.

Tried every solution using the combination keys, but nothing worked. I need your help in fixing this. What are the possible solutions in my problem?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by “nothing happens after recovery using internet?”   Were you able to boot the recovery OS?

Comment: did it suffer thermal shut down, how hot was it ? anyway, put it in a plastic bag and leave in the fridge to cool for 30 minutes down, then try

Comment: @Allan, when using CMD + Option + R, Start up from OS X Recovery over the Internet, after the progress/loading bar finishes, it redirects to the apple logo and then stuck up again. I wasn't able to boot the recovery OS because I doesn't go there even though I'm pressing the right keys during reboot. Option + D also works but it does not help.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I didn't know if it suffered from thermal shutdown. I'm just watching videos on youtube. That's the only thing that I'm doing before it shuts down. But when rebooting, it gets stuck on apple logo without loading bar and becomes hot over time.

Comment: This sounds like a logic board issue (failed component).  It's time to take it into a service center.

Comment: do you have Windows installed on your Mac ?

Answer (score 1):

Let me re-post all the hard work you did with the results and add some more you can try.

```
- Used CMD + R, but it doesn't go to recovery mode.
 - Used CMD + Option + R, nothing happens after recovery using internet.
 - Used Shift to enter safe mode, it doesn't go to safe mode.
 - Used CMD + Option + P + R, it doesn't fix anything. Still stuck at apple logo.
 - Used CMD + S, I just showed a verbose mode and the line said "End RandomSeed"
 - Used CMD + V, the last line prompted "End RandomSeed" and then freezes.
 - Pressed D, but nothing was seen defective in hardware.
```

Try following since it is still alive and "working" but not passing the `End RandomSeed`:

- Disconnect all external devices
- Hold Option key at reboot
- Boot from USB
- Do cool it down in the Fridge (not a joke)

Here is some background info. The `End RandomSeed` supposedly has to with failed RAM check.